# Geometric intuition - flatness of morphism of stacks

Tags: flatness, algebraic-stacks

I have seen interesting geometric intuition answers about flatness, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157827/geometric-intuition-for-flat-morphisms) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry/75358#75358).

I am not sure whether it still applies for [morphisms of stack](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06PV), and if yes how?
In partitcular,

- Can we say something about equidimensinal fibers of a flat morphism of stacks?
- Can we say something about the "mass" of fibers in a flat morphism of stacks $f: M \to \Bbb A^1$? (the fibers seen as groupoids in the moduli space $M$ have a cardinality called mass)

Thank you!

Comment: A flat morphism is, pretty much by definition, a morphism whose fibers and derived fibers agree. That’s the significance of flatness in general; it’s that you don’t have to take derived tensor products to get the “morally correct” fibers.

Comment: Many thanks @QiaochuYuan, could you please help me understand the definition of "derived" fibers? is it related to derived categories? I have some notions on stacks. Also, when the fibers and derived fibers agree, do you mean regarding cardinality or dimension? If I look at https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06FM, it looks like flatness of a morphism of stacks is defined as base change of a flat morphism of algebraic spaces so I am quite confused.

Comment: I mean they agree as in they’re canonically isomorphic. By derived fiber I mean taking derived fiber products; for affine things this means taking derived tensor products instead of ordinary ones, and flatness means exactly that the two are the same.

Comment: I see now @QiaochuYuan, many thanks for your help!